# Location of packages installed by apt-get and more

Tags: apt, package-management

A very basic question.

Whether all packages installed by `apt-get install` reside in the same folder? If yes, where?

If no, how to find the location?

I am in the case of installing `matplotlib Basemap` and it requires me to know where `libgeos_c` or `geos_c.h` file are located. I installed `libgeos-3.4.2` using `apt-get install` and had no idea to find those files.
**Further question**, what is `which`command doing? I did `which libgeos` and it didn't output, while doing `which python` gave `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: What do you need to know the location for?

Comment: @Pilot6, to set the environment variable. I added explanation to my question.

Answer (score 12):

The basic answer is no, different applications install in different locations, and consist of multiple files.  As a general rule the actual application will be installed in one of the locations in your PATH env variable, and you can check the directories in that variable with:

`echo $PATH`

But if you're trying to find a specific package's location you can use the dpkg command with the -L flag.  For example if you wanted to find all of the installed files for Apache2, you could run:

`dpkg -L apache2`